# CommandGroup CanExecute not working only sporadically

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, command

I have been trying to track this down for quite a while now and am drawing a total blank, so maybe there is something I am missing that others might see? NOTE: this is currently only being seen on one QA machine, thus why I cannot debug this like normal

I am using the Command Group code from [Josh Smith's code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25808/Aggregating-WPF-Commands-with-CommandGroup) with `CommandReference` implemented at the bottom of this post.

The problem is that the button that is bound to the `CommandGroup` is disabled, however the other two are not. Notice that the `CommandGroup` button is just a concatenation of the other two. So, it stands that if both are enabled, then so should the `CommandGroup` button. So, I am guessing this has to do with either the `CommandGroup` or `CommandReference`...any ideas would be helpful.

My current working hypothesis is that `ApplicationCommands.Close` being treated as an `ICommand` in the `CommandGroup` versus its normal RoutedUICommand is the problem. Especially as I can create an imbalance between two buttons bound to the same command by calling `ApplicationCommands.Close.CanExecute(null)` directly. But, I am not sure how to resolve this...

`RoutedCommand`'s `CanExecute` uses this `FilterInputElement(Keyboard.FocusedElement)` if `CanExecute` is called without an `IInputElement`....but in the case I am trying just above, I am calling `ApplicationCommands.Close` the same no matter where it's origin is from

CommandGroup

```
<Button Content="OK" IsDefault="True">
  <Button.Resources>
    <commonCommands:CommandReference x:Key="SaveCommand" Command="{Binding SaveDeviceCommand}"/>
  </Button.Resources>
  <Button.Command>
    <commonCommands:CommandGroup>
      <commonCommands:CommandGroup.Commands>
        <commonCommands:CommandReference Command="{StaticResource SaveCommand}"/>
        <x:Static Member="ApplicationCommands.Close"/>
      </commonCommands:CommandGroup.Commands>
    </commonCommands:CommandGroup>
  </Button.Command>
</Button>
<Button Content="Cancel" Command="ApplicationCommands.Close" IsCancel="True"/>
<Button Content="Apply" Command="{Binding SaveDeviceCommand}"/>
```

Command Reference:

```
public class CommandReference : Freezable, ICommand
{

public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof (ICommand), typeof (CommandReference), new PropertyMetadata(OnCommandChanged));

public ICommand Command
{
  get { return (ICommand) GetValue(CommandProperty); }
  set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
}

#region ICommand Members

public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
  return Command != null && Command.CanExecute(parameter);
}

public void Execute(object parameter)
{
  Command.Execute(parameter);
}

public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

private static void OnCommandChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
  var commandReference = dependencyObject as CommandReference;
  if (commandReference == null) return;
  var oldCommand = eventArgs.OldValue as ICommand;
  var newCommand = eventArgs.NewValue as ICommand;

  if (oldCommand != null)
    oldCommand.CanExecuteChanged -= commandReference.CanExecuteChanged;
  if (newCommand != null)
    newCommand.CanExecuteChanged += commandReference.CanExecuteChanged;
}

#endregion

#region Freezable

protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
{
  throw new NotImplementedException();
}

#endregion
}
```

Comment: In your command reference, instead of `SaveDeviceCommand` you have `SaveCommand`. Is that typo present here only or is it part of your code?

Comment: No, that is correct, notice that it is using the CommandReference key

Comment: Oh, missed that. Can't exactly put my finger on the cause, but it seems that the `CommandReference` has more nesting in it than it seems on first sight. Being `ICommand` by itself, and all properties being called "Command", is quite confusing to follow properly. Try this, on CommandReference in your CommandGroup, change the binding of Command property to: `Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource SaveCommand}, Path=Command}"`

Comment: @XAMeLi You are right, I dont know how I missed the nesting being the way it is. I will fix it up tomorrow and let you know if that solves the problem

Comment: @XAMeLi Well, the QA person finally tested this, and it is still not working....

Answer (score 0):

I am still waiting on QA to verify this, however I was able to get a similar issue that I could reproduce, and it turned out that my `ICommand` needed to be set up as

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
  add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
  remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}
```

instead of

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()...
```